# UML диаграмма вариантов использования для системы в сети кофеен, включающую бонусную программу лояльности

Tags: mysql, uml, crm, диаграммы, реализация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разрабатываю диаграммы UML для сети кофеен, реализующих бонусную программу лояльности. Построил диаграмму вариантов использования. Хотел бы узнать есть ли какие косяки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "Учет пользователей" немного конкретизируйте, лучше напишите "Создание, редактирование, удаление учетных записей" или около того. Преподы любят докапываться до таких названий, надо наиболее однобоко всё называть да попроще

Comment: Кассир не может ни списать бонусы ни продать товар...?

Comment: Может. Сейчас исправлю

Comment: Странно, что у покупателя отсутствует функция собственно покупки...

Comment: CRM-система, в основном,  рассчитана для администратора и касссира. Грубо говоря, это не онлайн-магазин. Получается,  кассир или админ оформляет заказ в системе.